# Cloud Endpoints calculated an Entity property at query time

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-datastore

How can I have a property in an Entity be calculated at query time?

For example if I had a `Post` Entity and I did `getPost(Long postId)`, I would like the `myPost.likes` property to be calculated at that moment by getting a count of how many `Like` Entities there are with the specific `Post` key.

OR

If this is not possible, I was considering storing a `Int likes` property for each `Post` Entity that I simply increment by one every time a new `Like` is inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both would work. For the latter i would use sharding counters if you expect many lps (likes per second). I would  use the first approach though since then a like can have meta like, when it was created, by whom, etc.

There's no real at query time calculation for that. You would have to write the query to sum up the likes yourself. In Objectify you could use the @OnLoad annotation to query it for each post, after a query. I strongly recommend that you don't do that though since that would be a query for each returned Post of a query. You really should do that manually to avoid redundant queries for likes when you don't even need them.

Comment: What I did was query for a list of `Post`'s, then loop through each `Post` and query how many `Like` Entities there are, and then set set the `Post`'s like amount to whatever amount there are. It is a lot of querying, but GAE can handle that right?

Comment: I would try and reduce the number of queries. I don"t have good idea how to do it right now though. I"ll have to sleep over it. Sharding counters wouldn"t improve the amount of queries, just limit the result count. Maybe i have a good idea tomorrow.

Comment: So i thought about it a bit more. Your original second approach is bad since you would run into the 1 write per second limitation, but this approach could be used with sharding counters which would behave similar to your current approach. The only difference is that the implementation of sharding counters you can find in the Google docs uses caching so in an average case you'd always have the number of likes in the cache and you would not have to query. So that would be the best option for performance. However, if your `Like`s have metadata or a ref to who liked the `Post`, this won't work.

Comment: To summarize: You should structure your entities for the best performance of your use cases. Since I don't know the exact use cases it's hard to tell what the best approach is. Since your current approach should work regardless of the use cases (even though it might give you a slight performance dip) i suggest you go with that and maybe do some experimentation on the side / later.

Comment: The approach I went with is the first comment I made to this answer - best I could come up with right now. I feel it could probably handle a lot of "likes" of a post coming in. I agree the second approach in the question is just bad because of the 1 write per second limitation. Thanks for the help!